# Explain this C macro used for string comparison with strcmp()

Tags: c, string, if-statement, macros

Can someone explain what this macro does and how it works?

```
#define STRCMP(a, R, b) (strcmp(a, b) R 0)
```

In code it is used as: `if(STRCMP(some_string, "==", " blabla"))`

What does the `R 0` in the macro mean? What is the macro doing in the `if` statement?

Comment: Just perform the expansion manually and you will get it.

Comment: `"=="` --> `==` ?

Comment: "R 0" doesn't really "mean" anything. The C preprocessor reads the `#define` and replaces `STRCMP(a, R, b)` with the string `(strcmp(a, b) R 0)` substituting `a`, `R`, and `b` as given in your code. The `#define` doesn't otherwise interpret what you give it. You should do a Google search on "C preprocessor macros".

Comment: So this is actually a good question even though the macro usage is really a bad idea. It had never occurred to me that operators could be used in macros this way. This is one of those horror uses of macros that I just never would have gone there.

Comment: I wouldn't expect `STRCMP(some_string, "==", " blabla")` to compile correctly. I'm surprised it's not `STRCMP(some_string, ==, " blabla")`.

Comment: As BLUEPIXY pointed out this won't compile due to double quotes surrounding `==`.  Need to get rid of double quotes.  But this is  a confusing MACRO.

Comment: @RichardChambers - proof once again that just because one *can* do something doesn't mean that one *should* do something. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the expansion yourself:

```
if(STRCMP(some_string, "==", " blabla"))

if((strcmp(some_string, " blabla") "==" 0 ))
```

Unfortunately, I think having the quotes around the `"=="` makes it incorrect, and likely won't compile.

The correct syntax would be:

```
if(STRCMP(some_string, ==, " blabla"))
```

And it is a test to see if variable `some_string` represents the text `" blabla"`, by using either an `==` or `!=` comparison.  (as is done with other values in C)

Answer (score 2):

First of all you mean:

```
if(STRCMP(some_string, ==, " blabla"))
```

and not:

```
if(STRCMP(some_string, "==", " blabla"))
```

i.e. without the quotes around the equality sign!

---

R is for the `==` and 0 for the result of [strcmp()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/).

So when you do:

```
STRCMP(some_string, ==, " blabla")
```

then your macro will have:

- `a` as `some_string`
- `R` as `==`
- `b` as " blabla"

which will make this:

```
(strcmp(a, b) R 0)
```

turn into this:

```
(strcmp(some_string, " blabla") == 0)
```

which checks if `some_string` is " blabla". If yes, the content of the parenthesis will be 1, i.e. true, otherwise false.

Answer (score 2):

Ah nice example....(but a overkill)
it is basically tricky way of performing different relational operator.
You use `==` or `<` etc. It basically have the lexicographic comparison.

Check `strcmp()`. And it's return value.

Macro is nothing but a text expansion. So when you expand it you can understand it.

> This function strcmp(str1,str2) return values that are as follows:
>
> ```
> if Return value < 0 then it indicates str1 is less than str2.
>
> if Return value > 0 then it indicates str2 is less than str1.
>
> if Return value = 0 then it indicates str1 is equal to str2.
> ```

Btw if you out it like the "==" then the operation won't work. You have to use ==

```
if(STRCMP(some_string, ==, " blabla")) --> correct use.
```

### Why "==" doesn't work?

Yo just replace it. Expand the macro ..it comes to 
`if(STRCMP(some_string, "==", " blabla"))`--> `(strcmp(a, b) "==" 0)` which doesn't abides by the Grammar of C.

Comment: @abelenky>: Oww missed it...I wil explain the whole thing to OP why is it so?..if it's ok with you.

Comment: @abelenky.: If it's right now..remove the dv because it gives the impression of WA which mine is certainly not. Thanks for pointing by the way.

Answer (score 1):

In the macro the `R` parameter is `==`.  So the macro expands to:

```
(strcmp(a, b) == 0)
```

In this case, it is testing to see if two strings are the same.  If `strcmp()` returns 0 that means the two strings contain the same characters.

That said, it's a dumb macro and you shouldn't use it.

EDIT: Comments below are correct, there should be no quotes around == or else it would still be quoted in the substitution.  OP replied that the quotes were a typo, so I have removed the quotes from my answer.

Comment: The quotes around `"=="` are kept in the macro substitution, and make the expression: `strcmp(a, b) "==" 0)`, which is not valid.

Comment: The `R` parameter is `"=="` not `==`. I would expect the macro to expand as `(strcmp(a, b) "==" 0)` which I would expect to fail at compilation time. But that having been said, +1 for "dumb macro". :-)

Comment: Thank you, guys! Quotes were just incorrect, some typo)))

Comment: @P.Alex glad we helped. **Accept** an answer please. =)